# Debugging two projects in the same workspace - IAR embedded workbench

Tags: iar, stm32f4discovery

I have two STM32F4 Discovery boards (Board 1 and Board 2, let's say) and two different projects for the two boards in the same workspace.

Board 2 is dependent on an input from Board 1. In order to realize this, I flash Board 2 with its code first and then flash Board 1 with its own code.

I would like to know if this is the right way of programming when using two boards. Also, is there a possibility that I can debug the code of Board 2 while running the code of Board 1 since Board 2 reacts due to actions of Board 1.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to debug both at the same time? What debugger are you using? I think that something like JTAG allows connecting multiple devices at the same time, but even then I don't know if it's possible to actually debug both at the same time.

Comment: The order in which you program the two controllers doesn't matter, but maybe the order in which you start them.